# No warning on assignment of int to short (gcc)

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings, implicit-conversion

I often use assignment of "longer" typed variables to "shorter" ones, for example `int` to `short` or `uint32_t` to `uint8_t`. One day i decided to find all such cases in my code using gcc, but found to my amazement that gcc didn't output any warnings!

```
int long_value;
short short_value;
std::cin >> long_value; // Example input: 32769
short_value = long_value; // MS Visual Studio complains here at warning level 4
std::cout << "Long: " << long_value << '\n'; // My example output: 32769
std::cout << "Short: " << short_value << '\n'; // My example output: -32767
```

Using `gcc -Wall` or `gcc -Wconversion` didn't help (gcc didn't output any warning). Actually, it never output any warning for any input and output type (e.g. `long` and `unsigned char`).

I have never found an actual bug in gcc so i am almost sure this behavior has a reason.

So why no warning?

Update: i use gcc 4.1.2.

Comment: @icecrime: gcc certainly needs to compile it. On platforms where short is shorter than int, it should and does warn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature was added in gcc 4.3 version. Previously this was not available.

I hope you are using gcc version 4.2 or below.

http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion confirms this.

This bug: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2707 also talks about it.

Answer (score 6):

I can't reproduce that. Compiling this code with gcc 4.4.5 with -Wconversion, I get

```
a.cc: In function ‘void f()’:
a.cc:7: warning: conversion to ‘short int’ from ‘int’ may alter its value
```

Comment: Yep, me too with 4.5.2 -Wconversion.